# Unable to integrate/sync the booking.com calendar using ical link with my django-python based website. give implementation steps

Tags: icalendar

I want to integrate the booking.com calender using ical link of booking.com with my danjo website where I am managing all the available rooms. gude me through the implementation steps

I tried executing the ical file and links but unable to integate it with my danjo web application

Comment: What have you tried to do, so far? What resources have you used? Have you made use of any and all available documentation from the services and APIs you are trying to use?